# Algoritmo para calcular a soma dos números digitados em portugol

Tags: algoritmo, portugol

Eu estou usando o Portugol Studio para estudar algoritmos em portugol. E estou com uma dificuldade em uma questão que o professor passou.

a questão é a seguinte:

> Elabore um algoritmo que solicite que o usuário entre com 10 números
>   inteiros quaisquer. Imprima a soma dos números digitados.

Meu algoritmo tá assim:

```
programa
{
    inteiro cont=0, numero, soma=0
    funcao inicio()
    {
        enquanto (cont<3)
        {
            cont++
            escreva ("Digite um número inteiro: ")
            leia (numero)
            limpa()
        }
        soma = soma+numero
        escreva ("\nA soma é: ", soma)
    }
}
```

Mas não me retorna a soma exata.

Comment: ----------
Rapaz! Valeu galera! Eu tava quebrando a cabeça aqui com essa soma...
Uma coisa tão simples......
Nem percebi que a variável tinha que ficar dentro do laço! Assim ela vai acrescentando os valores... Vlw pessoal!

Comment: Só não entendi porque seu laço vai de 0 a 2 se o exercicio pede para elaborar um algoritimo onde o usuário entre com 10 numeros inteiros.

Comment: É porque eu reduzi o tamanho pra obter o resultado... pra não ter que fazer o teste com os 10 valores! Na verdade o professor pediu com 100 valores! aí eu diminui pra 10 e consequentemente pra 2 hahaha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a parte

```
soma = soma+numero
```

Deve estar dentro do laço enquanto{}

Ficando assim:

```
programa
{
inteiro cont=0, numero, soma=0
    funcao inicio()
    {
enquanto (cont<3)
{
cont++
escreva ("Digite um número inteiro: ")
leia (numero)
soma = soma+numero//aqui
limpa()
}

escreva ("\nA soma é: ", soma)
    }
}
```

Assim cada vez que ele pedir o numero ele faz a soma dele na variavel soma e so depois que terminar as 2 voltas no enquanto ele mostra o valor de soma.

Answer (score 2):

Só está sendo feita a soma do último número digitado.

`soma = soma+numero` precisa estar dentro do bloco `enquanto`, desta forma sempre que o usuário digitar um número, este número será somado com o valor existente em **`soma`.**

```
programa
{
    inteiro cont=0, numero, soma=0
    funcao inicio()
    {
        enquanto (cont<3)
        {
            cont++
            escreva ("Digite um número inteiro: ")
            leia (numero)
            limpa()                
            soma = soma + numero
        }

        escreva ("\nA soma é: ", soma)
    }
}
```